# How to extend root partition in CentOS 7 (LVM, xfs filesystem)

Tags: linux, centos7, partition, disk

I am new to linux administration. I need to increase space for vg_centos-root from 8GB to 28GB. I can see xvda disk size is 30GB but not sure how to allocate that space in vg_centos-root (lvm)

OS: CentOS Linux release 7.8.2003

[image: List Block result lsblk]

[image: Df -h result]

Thanks in advance

I searched for solution but could not find proper one. Most of them are using /dev/sda (not xvda).